# Spark - I cannot increase number of tasks in local mode

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I tried to submit my application and change the `coalese[k]` in my code by different combinations:

Firstly, I read some data from my local disk:

```
val df = spark.read.option("encoding", "gbk").option("wholeFile",true).option("multiline",true).option("sep", "|+|").schema(schema).csv("file:///path/to/foo.txt")
```

#### Situation 1

I think local[*] means there are 56 cores in total. And I specify 4 * 4 = 16 tasks:

**spark-submit:**

```
spark-submit --master local[*] --class foo --driver-memory-8g --executor-memory 4g --executor-cores 4 --num-executors 4 foo.jar
```

**spark.write:**

```
df.coalesce(16).write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy("date").orc("hdfs://xxx:9000/user/hive/warehouse/ods/foo")
```

But when I have a look at spark history log server UI,there is only 1 task. In the data set, the 'date' column has only a single value.

So I tried another combination and removed `partitionBy`:

#### Situation 2

**spark-submit:**

```
spark-submit --master local[*] --class foo foo.jar
```

**spark.write:**

```
df.coalesce(16).write.mode("overwrite").orc("hdfs://xxxx:9000/user/hive/warehouse/ods/foo")
```

But the history server shows there is still only 1 task.

There are 56 cores and 256GB memory on my local machine.
I know in local-mode spark creates one JVM for both driver and executor, so it means we have one executor with the number of cores (let's say 56) of our computer (if we run it with Local[*]).

Here are the questions:

1. Could any one explain why my task number is always 1?
2. How can I increase the number of tasks so that I can make use of parallism?
3. Will my local file be read into different partitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark can read a csv file only with one executor as there is only a single file.

Compared to files which are located in a distributed files system such as HDFS where a single file can be stored in multiple partitions. That means your resulting Dataframe `df` has only a single partition. You can check that using `df.rdd.getNumPartitions`. See also my answer on [How is a Spark Dataframe partitioned by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66386963/how-is-a-spark-dataframe-partitioned-by-default/66392639#66392639)

Note that `coalesce` will collapse partitions on the same worker, so calling `coalesce(16)` will not have any impact at all as the one partition of your Dataframe is anyway located already on a single worker.

In order to increase parallelism you may want to use `repartition(16)` instead.