# Why is spark creating too many partitions for a dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I created a small dataframe using my own data by defining a schema with 5 columns in it in Databricks using Pyspark

```
schema=StructType(
[
StructField("col1",IntegerType(),True)
StructField("col2",StringType(),True)
StructField("col3",StringType(),True)
StructField("col4",IntegerType(),True)
StructField("col5",IntegerType(),True)
]
)
```

I created a dataframe of 27 rows

```
mydf=spark.createDataFrame(
        [
            (1, "abc","def",1,0),
            (2, "ghi","jkl",0,0),
            ,
            ,
            (26, "rty", "lki",1,1),
            (27, "xyz", "nhy",1,1),

        ],
        schema=schema
        )
```

> mydf.rdd.getNumPartitions()   --->It gives 40 or 48 or 144

**Question 1:**
Why is such a small data getting divided into 40 partitions. It is going to affect the performance? Is it the right way to create a dataframe if i have to create a manual dataframe?

**Question 2:**
When I do a join between a very large table and above dataframe 'mydf', it is doing a SortMergeJoin internally(checked using explain() method), Isn't it supposed to do a broadcast join?
(It is the case even when i don't see this "spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold = -1" in Advanced options of databricks)

**Question 3:**
How do i check the default max threshold size (within the cluster) for a dataframe to be eligible for broadcast join using a command in databricks?(though the default is 10 MB)

Comment: [How is a Spark Dataframe partitioned by default?][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66386963/how-is-a-spark-dataframe-partitioned-by-default

Comment: @mvasyliv I just checked it, Partitions are same as total number cores available for above case as said in the link